# How to Iterate the next 10 in a while loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to iterate a count of every 10 in a while loop. The code below counts 200 10 times and then stops, the reason it stops is that I need to store the first 10 in a spreadsheet, but that is another problem to solve, right now, I am not sure how to go about moving onto the next 10 counts taken from the first 10 count in the while loop below.

```
while (go) {
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if (i == 10) {
       go = false;
    
       while(go = false)
       {
         Utilities.sleep(10000)
       }
        if(Utilities.sleep == 10000)
        {
          go = true;
        }

    }
     rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
    i++;

  Logger.log(rows)
}
```

Also, please let me know if having a nested while loop in this is loop a good way to restart the loop again with the timer before it restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using modulo?

replace `if (i == 10) {` by `if (i%10 == 0) {`

This way, it will enter in your if statement every multiple of 10

Comment: Thanks for that it works, just curious How do I repeat it every time, so it runs let's say 90 times over?

Comment: you can either add an iterator in your if statment, or just add i < 900 in your if statement