# How to loop through a loop x number of times?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, while-loop

I would like to know how to loop through the while loop an x number of times over?

This is my while loop where it counts 200 10 times, what I want to do is keep looping that count another 90 times for example:

```
 while (go) {

    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if (i%10 == 0) {
       go = false;
       }
      
    }
     rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
    i++;

  Logger.log(rows)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70305749/how-to-iterate-the-next-10-in-a-while-loop) to get some context about your issue and I think what you are trying to do is to create a script that execute a commands every 10 iterations and you want to repeat it 90 times.

Here I added `for loop` and `while loop` that prints in every 10 iterations 90 times.

**While loop:**

```
function whileLoopCount(){
  var x = 1
  while (x <= 900){
    if((x % 10) == 0){
      Logger.log(x);
    }
    x++;  
  } 
}
```

**For Loop:**

```
function forLoopCount(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 900; i++){
    if((i % 10) == 0){
      Logger.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if my understanding of your issue is correct.

### Reference:

- [Loop and Iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: Just on the above examples you gave I am not sure, how would I fit that into my current while loop? my while loop needs to hit 200 10 times, then stop and restart the loop and x amount of time. So what I am really focusing in is just getting the while loop to repeat an x amount of time, which I could do with a for loop

Comment: @MrJnrDev - Which part of your code you hit the 200?

Comment: this part hits the 200 if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false; and then this part multiplies the 200 by 10 - if (i%10 == 0) {
       go = false;. so what the while loop is doing is for every 1-page increase by 200, and the reason I am doing it this way is that the google app script does not allow more than 6 minutes for a script to run and to calculate an entire database of thousands of records, the script cant populate everything. So the end result I need to is to loop the existing while loop an x number of times.

Comment: I updated the code above adding a 10-sec timer before the while loop starts so that when the repeat happens there is 10-sec pause between each interaction of the while loop

Comment: @MrJnrDev - Kindly confirm this. When your script hit 200 10 times, you want your script to sleep and move to the next set of 200's and repeat it until it reaches 90th iteration?

Comment: yes that is exactly it, I am just not sure how to go about it with my current while loop.

Comment: I am thinking if I create a new function that stores the row count function and do a for loop in the new function that might work to have the rowcount function repeated an x amount of times

Comment: @MrJnrDev - You can start by changing the condition in your while loop to `var x = 1
  while (x <= 900){`. This will give you a counter `x` which you can use to track the page and iteration of your loop. Also, modulo `%` does not multiply the number, instead it is used to get the remainder of 2 numbers. if a number is divisible to another number the modulo is 0.  That's why `if(i % 10) == 0)` works when the value of `x` is divisible by 10. (10, 20, 30 ... etc )

Comment: @MrJnrDev - I would prefer using for loop since you can easily track and modify the iteration of numbers in your loop. Also, make sure to include all necessary code to replicate your code. I noticed that some variables and functions declaration are missing.  Especially `getRecordsByPage`,  `i`, `go` and `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ttttttttt() {
  let x = 10;
  Logger.log([...Array.from(new Array(x).keys())].map(e => e));//[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
  let a = [];
  while(x--) {
   a.push(x); 
  }
  Logger.log(a);//[9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
}
```